# How do I enable proofs in the z3 c++ interface?

Tags: c++, z3

How do I enable proofs through the C++ interface in Z3?  I've tried the following to set :produce-proofs to true, but if I uncomment that line, I get a crash later when I try to add !conjecture to the solution, even before uncommenting the line that calls proof().  Based on the function in the example C++ file:

```
        void prove_example2(std::ostream& os) {
        os << "prove_example2\n";

        context c;
        solver s(c);
        params p(c);
        //p.set(":produce-proofs", true);
        s.set(p);

        expr x = c.int_const("x");
        expr y = c.int_const("y");
        expr z = c.int_const("z");
        sort I = c.int_sort();
        func_decl g = function("g", I, I);

        expr conjecture1 = implies(g(g(x) - g(y)) != g(z) && x + z <= y && y <= x,
            z < 0);


        s.add(!conjecture1);
        os << "conjecture 1:\n" << conjecture1 << "\n";
        if (s.check() == unsat) {
            os << "proved" << "\n";
            // Needs setup before calling
            //os << s.proof() << "\n";
        }
        else
            os << "failed to prove" << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `mk_proof_context` in [test_capi.c](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c/test_capi.c#L123). Proofs have to be enabled in the context as well as the solver. In C++ the easiest way is probably to set the global default parameter via

```
z3::set_param("proof", "true");
```

before creating any contexts or solvers.

Comment: looks like this works, but I have to remember to turn off the proof parameter again at some time after getting the proof, or it will crash a subseqent unit test (that isn't explicitly getting proofs at all).

Comment: If you have a (small, readable) test case to share, we're happy to look at those crashes!

Comment: Hi, Christopher.  The unit test that crashes, based on the example.cpp file in the distribution, is nonlinear_example1, when I've left the proof parameter on from a prior test (demorgan, where I was dumping the proof in the unsat case).  The others I've converted seem to be ok (through bitvector_example2 so far), and the crash goes away if I turn the parameter back off.  So I'm guessing that this is a specific conflict with the autoconfig stuff in nonlinear_example1, and you could try it on that example file.  We've got this under our build system, or I'd try it myself on the original distr.

Comment: Also, the z3 version we've got is a couple of years old, if that makes a difference.  We'll probably update it some time after our next release.

Comment: It looks like we also have another unit test, one of ours, that doesn't use autoconfig, but asserts in ast.cpp if the proof parameter is left on.   That one would be more work to get to you, though.

Comment: Re "a couple of years old": Definitely update to the latest version first. There have been many bugfixes related to segfaults with proof production enabled in those "couple of years". It's quite likely that the root problem has already been fixed.

Comment: We got our release out earlier this week, and updating the z3 version is on my to-do list.  I'll let you know if the crashes still happen when I get the new version installed.